# setting up nginx to rewrite domains to user directories

Tags: nginx

I would like to rewrite requests to (.*).server.org to go to www.server.org/do/$1

Basically any request that comes in as:
something.server.org should go to www.server.org/do/something

I would also like the ability to do something a little bit more clever:
something1.something2.server.org should go to www.server.org/do/something1/something2/

so something like:
(.*).(.*).server.org  should go to www.server.org/do/$1/$2

Would anyone have some knowledge they can drop on me as to how to set this up with nginx?

thanks,
Benny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Nginx and PCRE version is up to date and then use server_name captures: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names